# GKE Kubernetes Ingress not routing traffic to microservices

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm pretty new to Kubernetes and trying to deploy what I think is a pretty common use case onto a GKE cluster we have created with Terraform, microservices all hosted on one cluster, but cannot for the life of me get the routing to serve traffic to the correct services. The setup I'm trying to create is as follows:

- Deployment & Service for each microservice (`canvas-service` and `video-service`)
- Single Ingress (class GCE) on the cluster, hosted at a static IP, that routes traffic to each service based on path

The current config looks like this:

`canvas-service.yaml`

```yaml
# Deployment (Service Manager)
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: canvas-service-deployment
  labels:
    name: canvas-service
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: canvas-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: canvas-service
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: canvas-service
        image: gcr.io/emile-learning-dev/canvas-service-image:latest
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 8080
        ports:
          - name: root
            containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "4096Mi"
            cpu: "1000m"
          limits:
            memory: "8192Mi"
            cpu: "2000m"
---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: canvas-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: canvas-service
```

`video-service.yaml`

```yaml
# Deployment (Service Manager)
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: video-service-deployment
  labels:
    name: video-service
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: video-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: video-service
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: video-service
        image: gcr.io/emile-learning-dev/video-service-image:latest
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 8080
        ports:
          - name: root
            containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "4096Mi"
            cpu: "1000m"
          limits:
            memory: "8192Mi"
            cpu: "2000m"
---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: video-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: video-service
```

`services-ingress.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: services-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "services-ip"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: canvas-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /canvas/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: canvas-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /video/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: video-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

The output of `kubectl describe ingress services-ingress` looks like this:

```
Name:             services-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          34.107.136.153
Default backend:  canvas-service:80 (10.244.2.17:8080,10.244.5.15:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /canvas/*   canvas-service:80 (10.244.2.17:8080,10.244.5.15:8080)
              /video/*    video-service:80 (10.244.1.15:8080,10.244.8.51:8080)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s-be-30551--8ba41a687ec15071":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32145--8ba41a687ec15071":"HEALTHY"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-xlhz0sas-default-services-ingress-hqyvwyy1
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-xlhz0sas-default-services-ingress-hqyvwyy1
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-xlhz0sas-default-services-ingress-hqyvwyy1
              kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: services-ip
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                  From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync       9m36s                loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-xlhz0sas-default-services-ingress-hqyvwyy1" created
  Normal  Sync       9m34s                loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-xlhz0sas-default-services-ingress-hqyvwyy1" created
  Normal  Sync       9m26s                loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-xlhz0sas-default-services-ingress-hqyvwyy1" created
  Normal  IPChanged  9m26s                loadbalancer-controller  IP is now 34.107.136.153
  Normal  Sync       6m56s (x5 over 11m)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

For testing, I have a healthcheck route at `/health` for each service. What I'm running into is that when I hit `{public_ip}/health` (using the default backend) I get the expected response. But when I hit `{public_ip}/canvas/health` or `{public_ip}/video/health`, I get a `404 Not Found`.

I know it has something to do with the fact that the entire service route structure is on the `/canvas` or `/video` route, but thought that the `/*` was supposed to address exactly that. I'd like to basically make the root route for each service exist on the corresponding subpaths `/canvas` and `/video`. Would love to hear any thoughts you guys have as to what I'm doing wrong that's leading to traffic not being routed correctly.

If it's an issue with the GCP default Ingress resource or this isn't within its functionality, I'm totally open to using an `nginx` Ingress. But, I haven't been able to get an `nginx` Ingress to expose an  IP at all so figured the GCP Ingress would probably be a shorter path to getting this cluster working. If I'm wrong about this also please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the paths defined in `Ingress`. Changing the path type to `/video` and `/canvas` will make this work.

To understand the reason behind this, you need to read nginx ingress controller documentation about `path` and `pathType`. You can also use the regex pattern in the path according to the documentation here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/

Tip: When in doubt, you can always go to the nginx ingress controller pods and check the nginx.conf file about the `location` determined by nginx.

Comment: That's the thing, this is not an nginx ingress controller. It's the native GCP ingress, and I've tried to adapt the nginx ingress for a few days without success. Do you know of any working examples?